# Linux on Dell Optiplex 3020 + Unsupported NVMe Boot - No HDD lights

Tags: linux, ssd, nvme

I have a SFF Dell 3020 at work, which originally came with a 7200 RPM hard disk. I use Linux as my main OS, so naturally I upgraded the thing to a SATA SSD (a Kingston A400). Everything went fine, but the SSD was not able to sustain the performance I needed, so I upgraded yet again to a PCIe 3.0 x1 NVMe SSD (just a normal one with a PCIe x1 adapter).

Unfortunately, the machine doesn't seem to know how to boot from NVMe, but it can boot from USB. I used an old USB flash drive to mount the EFI partition for the system, mount the initramfs and boot the kernel. After that, the NVMe is mounted and the boot parition continues.

This is all fine now, but it seems that I have no HDD activity lights anymore. Is there a way to let the OS handle the HDD indicator, instead of the BIOS?

The OS is Arch Linux, with kernel version 6.4.10-zen

Comment: 1. What you reported is normal and expected. 2. No, the OS can't handle the HDD led.

Comment: Perhaps a third-party app can indicate disk I/O, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/554157/is-there-a-widget-that-simulates-a-disk-activity-led